# Can you exclude test dependencies from examples in cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the test dependencies for my package as part of the `[dev-dependencies]` in cargo.
I also have an example which has its own dependencies included using a feature.
The example cannot include the test dependencies (the example is for a `no_std` environment whereas the tests are run locally), otherwise it will not build.
I note that Cargo will include the dev dependencies with the examples https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#examples.

Is there a way to structure the test and example dependencies so that they are separate?

Or does this level of complexity necessitate a seperate `Cargo.toml` for the example?